# Duplicates when extracting data from html table using lxmk.html.xpath()

Tags: python, xpath, lxml.html

I am trying to extract data from this table at [Espn cricinfo](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;orderby=start;template=results;type=batting;view=innings). 
[image: Website being scraped]

Each row is comprised of the folowing format (Data replaced by headers):

`<tr class="data1">
    <td class="left" nowrap="nowrap"><a>Player Name</a> (Country)</td>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Minutes Played</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">Balls Faced</td>
    <td etc...
</tr>`

I have used the following code in a python script to capture the values in the table:

```
bats    = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[1]/a')
cntry   = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[1]/*')
run     = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[2]')
mins    = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[3]')
bf      = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[4]')
```

The data is then put into a csv file for storage.

All of the data is successfully being captured apart from the country of the player. The player name and country are stored inside the same `<td>` tag; however, the player name is also inside an `<a>` tag, allowing it to be captured easily. My problem is that the value captured for the players country (the `cntry` variable above) is the players name. I am sure that the code is incorrect but I am not sure why.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you have:

```
cntry = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[1]/*')
```

The '*' is looking for the child tags and passes by any text.

You can replace your line of code with this to grab the text instead of the tags:

```
cntry = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[1]/text()')
```

See if that works for you.

EDIT

---

To remove the white spacing at beginning of each item, just do the following:

```
cntry = content.xpath('//tr[@class="data1"]/td[1]/text()')
cntry = [str(x).strip() for x in cntry]
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. There is however a blank space before the country name. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @PadraigScott it is probably due to the spacing between the player name and the country. I'll update my answer to remove the white spacing